# Chef create recursive directories with several variables

Tags: chef-infra

In my chef-recipe I need to create directories like this (tree):

```
/var/www/common
    + variable_1 (array)
        + variable _2 (array)
            + variable_3 (array)
```

With giving them common permissions. I've googled already, but can't choose the right way to do this for that kind of tree..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something along the line:

```
variable_1.each do |v1|
  directory "/var/www/common/#{v1}" do
    owner 'me'
    group 'me'
    mode '755'
  end
  variable_2.each do |v2|
    directory "/var/www/common/#{v1}/#{v2}" do
      owner 'me'
      group 'me'
      mode '755'
    end
    variable_3.each do |v3|
      directory "/var/www/common/#{v1}/#{v2}/#{v3}" do
        owner 'me'
        group 'me'
        mode '755'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

A hash may be a better way to loop over, maybe creating the leaf directories and doing a recursive `chown` and `chmod` could be another way to do it.

The main drawback here is that the `directory` resource in chef set the perms only on the last one even if it creates the parents with `recursive` attribute.

Comment: @coderanger I take note for the permissions. Why do I have the exact opposite idea in mind ? I'll have to search on the mailing list for that I think. Could it be to makes files setuid we need to use numeric modes ?

Comment: Nope, they are always equivalent but the numeric modes are way more error prone because `mode 0644` is _very_ different from `mode 644` and that can often be easy to overlook. The fact that they are octal numbers is cute, but the way humans use files modes is as symbolic strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Chef. You can use the `recursive` option on the `directory` resource to easily create nested folders, however only the leaf folder uses the requests permissions, all others just get whatever the umask dictates.

The easiest way do this would be a loop:

```
my_variable = ['/var/www/common', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
path_so_far = ''

my_variable.each do |path|
  path_so_far = File.join(path_so_far, path)
  directory path_so_far do
    owner 'me'
    group 'me'
    mode '755'
  end
end
```

Comment: I may be wrong but I understood the OP has an array for each level. I don't see how to adapt this answer for this case (let's say there's bar and bar2 at second level, how to create the array at first ?

Comment: Yeah, not sure if the _1 is supposed to be an index or different variables. One or the other answer is correct :)